# .net mvc with StructureMap dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a .net webAPI project where we are using dependency injection (StructureMap I believe) to provide our controllers instances of per-session Data Access Objects.  This part works great.

What I now need to do is provide an instance of AuthorizationFilterAttribute with a DataAccessObject.

The AuthorizationFilterAttribute is used via an annotation.  For example:

```
[ApiKeyAuthorization]
public DataModel ControllerAction(int id) { }
```

That will ensure that before the controller gets to run, authorization is checked.

What I need is for that ApiKeyAuthorization object to be created with reference to my shared-per-session Database Access Object.

Is there an easy way to make that happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several similar questions on SO about dependency injection to Action Filters. Here are few:

[Ninject and MVC3: Dependency injection to action filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078046/ninject-and-mvc3-dependency-injection-to-action-filters)
[How to use dependency injection with an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102138/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-an-attributes)
[Injecting dependencies into ASP.NET MVC 3 action filters. What's wrong with this approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192543/injecting-dependencies-into-asp-net-mvc-3-action-filters-whats-wrong-with-this/7194467#7194467)

Jimmy Bogart's blog post (linked from one of the answers): http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/03/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-filters/

Another StructureMap based solution: http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/1/27/structuremap-action-filters-and-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3

An interesting solution for allowing constructor based injection for action filters: http://iridescence.no/post/Constructor-Injection-for-ASPNET-MVC-Action-Filters.aspx

Hope it will take you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to go with the proxy-based solution.  I haven't implemented it yet, but it looks perfect.