# Ninject Property Injection not working on ActionFilters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an interface and a class that implements that interface

```
public interface ISessionVariables
{
    bool IsSessionTokenValidated { get; set; }
}

public class HttpContextSessionVariablesAdapter : ISessionVariables
{
    private T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    private void Set(string key, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }

    public bool IsSessionTokenValidated
    {
        get { return Get<bool>("IsSessionTokenValidated"); }
        set { Set("IsSessionTokenValidated", value); }
    }
}
```

I bind the interface to implementation using Ninject:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ISessionVariables>().To<HttpContextSessionVariablesAdapter>();
}
```

I have an ActionFilter

```
public class ValidateSessionTokenAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public ISessionVariables SessionVariables { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (SessionVariables.IsSessionTokenValidated == false)
        {
            throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "User session has expired");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Strange bug:

If i add the `ValidateSessionTokenAttribute` to an ActionResult, `SessionVariables` property gets populated.

```
[ValidateSessionToken]
public ActionResult Index()
{

}
```

If i bind the same filter to all ActionResults, (in FilterConfig), the `SessionVariables` property is always `null`.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ValidateSessionTokenAttribute());
    }
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ninject and MVC3: Dependency injection to action filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078046/ninject-and-mvc3-dependency-injection-to-action-filters)