# Ninject to Action Filter for MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

First of all, I'm new to `Ninject`.

**I'm trying to bind to Action Filter in MVC4.**

I found many questions in SO but all of them are about MVC3-2 and most of them are a couple of year old - [MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192543/injecting-dependencies-into-asp-net-mvc-3-action-filters-whats-wrong-with-this), [Filter configurations](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Filter-configurations), [Ninject and MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078046/ninject-and-mvc3-dependency-injection-to-action-filters)

The following is my test code -

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IProductRepository _productRepository { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var products = _productRepository.Products; // this is null

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}

public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel _kernal;

    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        _kernal = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
       System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null ? null : 
           (IController)_kernal.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        // This is working in ProductController
        _kernal.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();

        // I'm trying to make this work!
        _kernal.BindFilter<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();       
    }
}

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
           new NinjectControllerFactory());
    }
}
```

**I tried to add `using Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax;` to get `BindFilter`.**

However, I could not find `Ninject MVC4`in `NuGet`

### Should I use Ninject.MVC3?

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use Ninject.MVC3, it works just fine in MVC4 as the nuget package will setup version forwarding.  This version will not work directly with WebAPI though, and you will need to install an extension package if you intend to use Ninject with WebAPI.